# Azure Webapp wheels --find-links does not work

Tags: python, azure, pypi, azure-web-app-service, python-wheel

I have been struggling with --find-links for an entire day, and I will be very grateful if sb could help me out here.

I have been developing using python3.4 and one of the new features I added uses Azure Storage( the most recent version) and it requires cryptograph, which requires cffi, idna, etc...
However, when I try to test it against Azure Webapp, the deployment failes, saying 'error : unable to find vcvarsall.bat'

With some research, I figured putting --find-links wheelhouse at the top of my requirements.txt and have wheels(cffi-1.8.2-cp34-cp34m-win32.whl (md5) and cryptography-1.5-cp34-cp34m-win32.whl (md5)) located at wheelhouse folder in the root should work. This was not helping at all, and I was running into same problems.

I tried --no-index and it gives "Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement cffi==1.8.2". Somebody says if I want to use --no-index, then I should have all wheels located in wheelhouse; otherwise, i will get that error.

With this, I would like to use my wheels for cffi and cryptograph and the rest download from pypi. Anyone have any clue...? HELP!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not the only one in that situation:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/issues/219

It seems for an unknown reason that the version of pip on the WebApp machine does not detect the platform tag as "win32" (it's why it does not find your wheel).

Several solutions:

- Move to Py3.5:
  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2016/08/04/upgrading-python-on-azure-app-service/
- Use a deploy script to easy_install your wheel:
  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-configure/#troubleshooting---package-installation
- Force the version of storage to 0.32.0 in your requirements.txt file (does not require cryptography) if you don't need the latest features. Read the release note of storage 0.33.0 to figure out if you need it:
  https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/releases/tag/v0.33.0

Comment: Thanks! For a quick fix, I have implemented azure storage with an older version which does not require cryptography, but I will have a closer look at your solutions as soon as I am done with the other feature that I have been working on! :)